# value mkString is not a value of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int]

Tags: scala

I changed this line:

```
val ratedNum = rows.sortBy(- _._2).map{case (user , ratednum) => ratednum}.take(20).mkString("::")
```

to:

```
val ratedNum = rows.sortBy(- _._2).map{case (user , ratednum) => ratednum}.mkString("::")
```

But Eclipse is giving me an error hint: `value mkString is not a value of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int]`

What does this error mean?

Comment: Also... though things like `map{case (user , ratednum) => ratednum}.take(20)` work... would it not be better to make it more readable as `map({case (user , ratednum) => ratednum}).take(20)` or `map {case (user , ratednum) => ratednum} take 20`

Answer (score 5):

```
val ratedNum = rows.sortBy(- _._2).map{case (user , ratednum) => ratednum}
```

This returns an [`org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int]`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.8.1/api/core/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html) which is not [`GenTraversableOnce`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce). Although it has a lot of methods defined which makes it like a Scala collection of `Int`, **it is not** (`abstract class RDD[T] extends Serializable with Logging`). It's a bit like a promise of a collection `Int`. You have to poll the collection out before you `mkString` with the results.

Call `.collect()` on the `RDD[Int]` before you perform `mkString`.

```
val ratedNum = rows.sortBy(- _._2).map{case (user , ratednum) => ratednum}.collect.mkString("::")
```

Or you can add an implicit conversion:

```
implicit def toArray[T](rdd: RDD[T]) = rdd.collect()
```